# Перемещение чисел в одномерном массиве

Tags: c++

Пожалуйста, решите задачку.

> В одномерном массиве все отрицательные числа переместить в начало массива, а остальные в конец с сохранением порядка следования. Дополнительный массив заводить не разрешается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. проверяет элемент массива в цикле
2. если меньше 0, меняем с первым
3. если нет берем следующий элемент
4. вводим счетчик(т.е. 2й итератор), который будет следить за номером ячейки, в которую/с которой меняем значения

Наверно, даже можно счетчик 2-ого итератора ввести. Типа, если текущие значение меньше 0, тогда +1, если нет, но нечего не прибавлять. Это позволит всегда находится на последнем элементе, с которым можно будет провести обмен отрицательного числа.

Answer (score 1):

Эту задачу можно рассматривать как частный случай стабильной сортировки без использования дополнительной памяти.

В качестве стабильной сортировки хорошо подходит сортировка слиянием, сложность которой - O(n*log(n)):

```
void merge_sort(BidirIterator first, BidirIterator last) {
    auto n = std::distance(first, last);
    if (n < 2) return;  // Nothing to sort.
    auto middle = std::next(first,  n / 2);
    merge_sort(first, middle, cmp);
    merge_sort(middle, last, cmp);
    std::inplace_merge(first, middle, last);
}
```

Алгоритм `std::inplace_merge` использует O(n) памяти.
Однако он нам не нужен, т.к. у нас ключ сортировки имеет всего два значения (true и false).
После двух рекурсивных вызовов merge_sort мы получаем последовательность вида

```
000011111000111111
         ^_ middle
```

И всё что нам надо сделать - это применить `std::rotate` чтобы поменять две средние части местами.

Поэтому мы можем переписать наш алгоритм следующим образом:

```
template<typename BidirIterator, typename Predicate>
BidirIterator stable_partition(BidirIterator first, BidirIterator last, Predicate pred) {
    auto n = std::distance(first, last);
    if (n == 0) return first;
    if (n == 1) return pred(*first) ? last : first;
    auto b = std::next(first,  n / 2);
    auto a = ::stable_partition(first, b, pred);
    auto c = ::stable_partition(b, last, pred);
    // Rotate:
    // [11111|0000|11111|0000]
    // F     A    B     C    L
    // [11111|11111|0000|0000]
    //             Result
    return std::rotate(a, b, c);
}
```

Пример использования:

```
int a[6] = {1, -1, 2, 3, -2, -3};
::stable_partition(a, a + 6, [](int x){ return x < 0; });
for (auto x : a) std::cout << x << ' ';
// Выводит -1 -2 -3 1 2 3
```

(`::` нужно чтобы не было конфликта с `std::stable_partition`)

Comment: Круто! Недавно у кого-то здесь была похожая задача: написать компаратор для сишного `qsort`, который бы отсортировал положительные числа, а отрицательные унёс в конец массива, не меняя порядок. (И поскольку `qsort` нестабилен, решения мы не нашли.)